# Writing Factories around values that already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I've been using Factory Girl to create some basic objects in development when I want to test out an idea, and I commonly run into this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Login has already been taken
```

If I've run `FactoryGirl.create :user` in development mode once and left that user in the db, I'll have to run that command twice if I try to do this again after closing the console.  Basically, sequences are getting reset between console instances.

Has anyone come up with a way to write factories such that they'll generate unique results each time?  I'm aware that I can use random generators to pick a value from a large domain, minimizing the chance of a collision.  I'd like to find a cleaner method, if available, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a sequence for this.

```
Factory.sequence(:email) do |n|
  "tester#{n}@example.com"
end

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.name "Tester"
  f.email {Factory.next :email}
  f.password "tester"
end
```

Source: [about half way down the page.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage)

**EDIT**

Upon re-reading, it seems that you are trying to create the data in development mode.

You should use the seeds.rb file for this and maintain a counter.

```
index = User.count || 1

User.create([
  {:email => "user#{index++}@example.com",
   :password => "password"},
  {:email => "user#{index++}@example.com",
   :password => "password"}
])
```

Comment: Yep, I'm using sequences already.  I'd like some way to persist the sequence--but setting it to the highest primary key on startup should work too (deletions could cause collisions when using object count).  My use case is creating objects in the console to test out an idea before coding it up.  Seeding still feels a bit clumsy for that purpose, as I'd have to create seed definitions for each model I foresee myself using in future code, then run a rake task and look up the objects created in the console.